# MIPS subroutine vs C functions

Tags: c, mips

Say I have the following C code:

```
int array[10] = {10, 5, 2, 20, 20, -5, 3, 19, 9, 1};
void main(void)
{
      printArray(0, 9);
}
void printArray(int startIndex, int endIndex)
{
      // prints out the numbers in the order starting from startIndex
      // and ending at endIndex
}
```

I would translate this C code into MIPS as so:

```
    .text
    .globl main

main:
   # ...

    .text
    .globl printArray
printArray:
    # play with registers
print:
# used to loop
```

I am confused. In that MIPS code, is `main` and `printArray`, by being `global`, would be the equivalent of a C function, right? But would print also be? If not, does `print` have an equivalent in C?

Comment: Do you, by any chance, use a label print inside printArray() function?

Comment: I changed my code so that the print label is inside printArray - the code was more to clarify my question than a real code (print could have been another label)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variable and Function Scope isn't really a "thing" in Assembly. `.globl` is a directive to the assembler, but the target it's referring to is still just a label for a memory location. So when you say, "would [`main` and `printArray`] be the equivalent of a C function?", the answer is yes and no.

Yes, you can jump or branch to the memory address labelled by `main:` or `printArray:` (or `print:`). So in that way, it's a little bit like calling a function in a high-level language.

No, it's not really "equivalent" to a C function, because it doesn't have any automatic handling for parameters and return values. You have to pass parameters in registers, and you have to return values in registers - you even have to use a register (`$ra`) to get back to the calling function. And there isn't any automatic preservation of the caller's registers - you have to push them on the stack and pop them off, or else the calling function will lose whatever it had put in them.

Sorry if that's more basic than you needed - hope it helps!

Comment: So I guess my question is moot because I am asking for something that does not really exists... I was trying to find similarities where there are none... Thanks!